# How I can view rows and columns of 'Adult' Dataset in R

Tags: r

How I can view rows and columns of 'Adult' Dataset in R? I just started learning R.
Any help is appreciated.Pls refer to the screenhot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbeQx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

First, start by running `str` to see the **str**ucture of your dataset.

```
str(Adult)
#Formal class 'transactions' [package "arules"] with 3 slots
#  ..@ data       :Formal class 'ngCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with #5 slots
#  .. .. ..@ i       : int [1:612200] 1 10 25 32 35 50 59 61 63 65 #...
#  .. .. ..@ p       : int [1:48843] 0 13 26 39 52 65 78 91 104 117 #...
#  .. .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 115 48842
#  .. .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
#  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
#  .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
#  .. .. ..@ factors : list()
#  ..@ itemInfo   :'data.frame':    115 obs. of  3 variables:
#  .. ..$ labels   : chr [1:115] "age=Young" "age=Middle-aged" #"age=Senior" "age=Old" ...
#  .. ..$ variables: Factor w/ 13 levels "age","capital-gain",..: 1 #1 1 1 13 13 13 13 13 13 ...
#  .. ..$ levels   : Factor w/ 112 levels "10th","11th",..: 111 63 #92 69 30 54 65 82 90 91 ...
#  ..@ itemsetInfo:'data.frame':    48842 obs. of  1 variable:
#  .. ..$ transactionID: chr [1:48842] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

This tells you that `Adult` is an S4 object with three slots, `data`, `itemInfo` and `itemsetInfo`.

1. The slot `data` is a sparse matrix created by package `Matrix`;
2. The slot `itemInfo` is a `data.frame`;
3. The slot `itemsetInfo` is also a `data.frame`.

S4 objects' slots are accessed with operator `@`. In order to see what is in those slots, run

```
Adult@data
Adult@itemInfo
Adult@itemsetInfo
```

In the case of the two dataframes, you might prefer to run

```
head(Adult@itemInfo)
head(Adult@itemsetInfo)
```

since they have 115 and 48842 observations, respectively and don't fit in a screen display.

Comment: One should use setters, getters and generic functions normally implemented by package which provides class functionality. E.g. `summary(Adult[1:5, ])`, `image(Adult)` etc...

Answer (score 0):

To get the text output shown in your example you can use this:

```
cat(dim(mtcars)[1], "transactions (rows)\n", dim(mtcars)[2], "items (cols)")
#32 transactions (rows)
# 11 items (cols)
```

Change `mtcars` with `Adult`(or any `data.frame`). `cat` lets you print out to the console, and `dim()` gets you rows and columns of the data.

Similarly to `str` from base `R`, you can use `glimpse` from `dplyr` package:

```
install.packages("dplyr") # run this the first time to install the package
dplyr::glimpse(mtcars)

# Observations: 32
# Variables: 11
# $ mpg  <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 17.3, 15.2, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 32...
# $ cyl  <dbl> 6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 8, 4
# $ disp <dbl> 160.0, 160.0, 108.0, 258.0, 360.0, 225.0, 360.0, 146.7, 140.8, 167.6, 167.6, 275.8, 275.8, 275.8, 472.0,...
# $ hp   <dbl> 110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 1...
# $ drat <dbl> 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 2.93, 3.00, 3.23, 4....
# $ wt   <dbl> 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440, 3.460, 3.570, 3.190, 3.150, 3.440, 3.440, 4.070, 3.730, 3.780, 5.250,...
# $ qsec <dbl> 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20.00, 22.90, 18.30, 18.90, 17.40, 17.60, 18.00, 17.98,...
# $ vs   <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
# $ am   <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
# $ gear <dbl> 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4
# $ carb <dbl> 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2
```

You have the number of Observations (rows) and Variables (columns), and each variables listed with it's format type, and values.